# Showing big data reporting on the web without performance being affected?

Tags: web, report, bigdata

We are integrating reports into our web application.

Our reports are currently not optimised and takes a long time to load. Every time the report is loaded, SQL queries are made, then the data is displayed onto the screen, which is not practical.

As a get around we have decided to write a cron which gets all of the reporting data and put it in a tsv file on the server, avoiding the need to do SQL queries all the time. This cron runs every 24 hours and updates the tsv file.

The problem arises when we have a report that spans a very long period of time and contains 1000s of record, the report gets stuck in a loop.

How can we display such data without our web app being affected?

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination (i.e display 100-200 records at a time or something) instead of showing or querying all the records at the same time.

For someone who wants to "view" all the data, please use summaries/aggregated data instead of showing all the records.

If someone still wants to drill down deeply, then TSV export option used by you sounds good.